# How WCF clients know about server types

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have WCF bassicHttpBiding service .
My web functions are returning some custom defined types.

```
[DataContract]
public class PcbInfoEntry
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ReflowPcbId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PcbId { get; set; }
}
```

But how actually the client knows the definition of the class ?
What is happening in the proxy that is generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server exposes a [WSDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) (Web Services Description Language). Simply point your browser to `http://example.com/myservice/service.svc?wsdl` and you will see the full definition of your service. All the types and methods that it exposes. When generating a client side proxy, `svcutil.exe` uses this information to generate the corresponding client side proxy classes.

WSDL is a SOAP standard. No matter what language your service is written to, if it exposes a WSDL, you could generate client proxy easily.

WCF can also publish its metadata through a MEX endpoint which implements the WS-Metadata Exchange standard allowing for clients to discover its types.

Comment: where sitting the description of the  DTOs that are returned by my web methods . because in my WSDLs I couldnt see it.

Comment: @NightWalker, there are references/links in the main WSDL to other pages such as for example `http://example.com/myservice/service.svc?wsdl=wsdl0` and `http://example.com/myservice/service.svc?xsd=xsd0` and so on.

Comment: yes it helps. One more question in the same area . one of my web functions returns some DTO and it doesn't have on it [DataContract]
 attribute , but still I saw it in the wsdl and my clients using it ok. The question is why I need the [DataContract]
 attributes .

Comment: @NightWalker, you don't need them since .NET 3.5 SP1. You can remove them and have a POCO. All public properties will be exposed. Now if you have some object that never appears neither as input or output parameter to any of your service methods, then you cannot expose it in the WSDL as it will never be used by the clients. And if on the other hand you expose only a base type on your service methods, and you have some derived types, those derived types won't be exposed in the metadata. In this case you need to use [known types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx).